# Excel Macro - Union of table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro that copy three tables from different worksheets and paste it together in a new worksheet.

The number of rows in the tables are not always the same. Therefore, I need a macro with a 'dynamic' "LastRow" parameter so that every time I update one single table the result of the macro is updated.

I tried to run this macro:^

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("Discussed Files").Select
Range("Table1[#Headers]").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All data").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Discussed Files").Select

Range("Table1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All data").Select
Range("A2").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Files within 3 Days").Select

Range("Table3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All data").Select
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Files 10.04.17").Select

Range("Table5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All data").Select
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$Y$" & lastRow), ,     xlYes).Name = _
    "Table14"
Range("Table14[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table14").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
```

I cannot understand exactly what the macro is doing. It ends up woth a table having number of rows equal to first sheet but data inside the table are 'randomly' taken from the other sheets.
Moreover, the selection to make the result a table is not working properly.

Comment: For starters, you define `lastrow` before you paste anything so it is not up to date as it were (and it will need to be updated as you add more data). Also you should specify a sheet as it's not clear which it is referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment above (have also removed unnecessary Selects)

```
Sub x()

Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("All data")
    Sheets("Discussed Files").Range("Table1[#All]").Copy
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Files within 3 Days").Range("Table3").Copy
    .Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Files 10.04.17").Range("Table5").Copy
    .Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("$A$1:$Y$" & lastRow), , xlYes).Name = "Table14"
    .ListObjects("Table14").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't update `lastRow` between steps, so you are basically pasting them one over another into same spot because the `lastRow` does not update after you paste one of your tables, it retains the same value from the beginning of your code in each:

```
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
```

Also, this code will return last row **with data in it** so if you are pasting into clean sheet, you are pasting all tables into the same spot:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

EDIT:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("All data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("Discussed Files").Range("Table1[#All]").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

lastRow = Sheets("All data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("Files within 3 Days").Range("Table3").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All data").Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

lastRow = Sheets("All data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("Files 10.04.17").Range("Table5").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All data").Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

lastRow = Sheets("All data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("All data").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$Y$" & lastRow), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table14"
Range("Table14[#All]").Select
Sheets("All data").ListObjects("Table14").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
```